# parse issue Expected identifier or "("

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to create a noise app but have got stuck. I am not a developer and am just creating this for fun!

The problem is that I am getting an error saying "Expected identifier or '('" On the "@interface ViewController : NSObject  :UIViewController" line in ViewController.h.

The code is for the ViewController.h is:

```
@interface ViewController : NSObject  :UIViewController {
}

-(IBAction)sound1;
-(IBAction)sound2;
-(IBAction)sound3;
-(IBAction)sound4;
-(IBAction)sound5;
-(IBAction)sound6;

@end
```

And the code for the ViewController.m is:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController : NSObject;

-(IBAction)five {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"sound1", CFSTR("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}

-(IBAction)cramp {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"sound2", CFSTR("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}

-(IBAction)cycling {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"sound3", CFSTR("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}

-(IBAction)iLoveBanking {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"sound4", CFSTR("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}

-(IBAction)sound5 {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"sound5", CFSTR("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}

-(IBAction)sound6 {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"sound6", CFSTR("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}

@end
```

HELP!!!!!!

Comment: Remember to up vote and accept the answer that solved your question.

Answer (score 2):

This code is crying out for refactoring that will..

1. Help find what is causing the problem.
2. Make it a lot easier to work with.

Here you go...

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)five {
    [self playSoundWithName:@"sound1"];
}

-(IBAction)cramp {
    [self playSoundWithName:@"sound2"];
}

-(IBAction)cycling {
    [self playSoundWithName:@"sound3"];
}

-(IBAction)iLoveBanking {
    [self playSoundWithName:@"sound4"];
}

-(IBAction)sound5 {
    [self playSoundWithName:@"sound5"];
}

-(IBAction)sound6 {
    [self playSoundWithName:@"sound6"];
}

- (void)playSoundWithName:(NSString *)name
{
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef)name, CFSTR("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}

@end
```

Also, your header should be...

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

If you're only calling the IBAction methods from buttons then you don't need to declare them in the header at all.

Comment: Thank you for helping but unfortunately xcode says there are problems. What I want to do is to create a soundboard that plays noises when buttons are pressed. Would you mind writing the code for me? I will place the sound files into the correct folders after you written the code. @Fogmeister

Comment: @HarryTGraham What are the problems that Xcode is displaying? If you want me to write it for you I can send you an invoice and do it properly. :)

Comment: Thank you that would be great! The problems are that in the " (void)playSoundWithName:(NSString *)name
{
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef)name, CFSTR("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}

Comment: Part there is a problem on each line. The top one says "expected a type", the second line says "Use of undeclared indentifier "CFURLRef" @Fogmeister

Comment: @HarryTGraham then I'd suggest finding a tutorial about playing sounds.

Comment: The code that I orignally found was from a tutorial but there are loads of problems with it! Plse help! @Fogmeister

Answer (score 1):

> @interface ViewController : NSObject  :UIViewController

This is wrong, you cannot have multiple classes. You can only subclass from one.
Since you have some IBActions in .m file, I guess you are using this as a view controller and in .h file remove NSObject. `@interface ViewController : UIViewController`

And in .m it should be

`@implementation ViewController`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inherit from two classes; just use `UIViewController`:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
```

Comment: Thank you where do I put that? In .m or .h? @trojanfoe

Comment: @HarryTGraham In the header (`.h`) file.

Answer (score 0):

write .h file like this

```
   @interface ViewController :UIViewController

  -(IBAction)sound1;
-(IBAction)sound2;
 -(IBAction)sound3;
-(IBAction)sound4;
-(IBAction)sound5;
  -(IBAction)sound6;
  @end
```

and .m file replace NSObject with UIViewController

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
      @implementation ViewController : UIViewController;
```